# sprite3d objects do not retain depth when there is a transparent object underneath

Tags: game-development, godot

Im working on ship game. For ship's im using sprite3D objects. (Because i wanted to implement 2.5D style). And my water is MeshInstance3D (plane). When im trying to make it semi-transparent by setting alpha to lower than max and enabling transparency. As on screenshot below.

[image]

Ships seem to be under water object. It's like water is rendered always after ships.
[image]

Here is screenshot with disabled transparency of water to give you idea how ships are positioned in relation to the water.
[image]

So they are clearly above it, and it looks like not.
Additionally, this problem only show for sprites 3d. Here is random cube that looks normal.
[image]

Additionally, when i change camera projection to perspective from orthogonal. It works a little better, but still with flaws, because if something is far from camera it again looks like under water. (I tried to look on y coordinate but it doesnt change so its not that.

[image]

What could be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Set depth draw to never, so the material does not change the depth buffer.

Alternatively: set transparency to depth pre-pass, and leave depth draw to opaque only.

Comment: I did what you said and still same result. :(